# How to access children, sub-children and their children from json formatted string

Tags: c#

This is API Link.
https://api.indix.com/v2/offersPremium/products?countryCode=US&q=macys&name=10168--Electronics&app_id=dbffc3ab&app_key=6c1608f7ba90259040aa98132f29b433

and I Get the values of mpns,upcs,maxSalePrice from this API link.I am getting the values in this format

```
foreach (JToken child in result.Children())
{
    foreach (JToken grandChild in child)
    {
        foreach (JToken grandGrandChild in grandChild)
        {
            var upsc = System.Convert.ChangeType(result["upcs"].ToString(), type);
            var MPN = System.Convert.ChangeType(result["mpns"].ToString(), type);
            var maxSalePrice = System.Convert.ChangeType(result["maxSalePrice"].ToString(), type);
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives values only one time ,I got all values of these objects related from the API link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your `result["upcs"]` etc. with `grandGrandChild["upcs"]`:

```
string url = "https://api.indix.com/v2/offersPremium/products?countryCode=US&q=macys&name=10168--Electronics&app_id=dbffc3ab&app_key=6c1608f7ba90259040aa98132f29b433";
var type = typeof(string);

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
JObject results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(wc.DownloadString(url));

foreach (var result in results["result"]["products"])
{
    string CatId = (string)result["categoryId"];
    string catname = ddlRetailerName.SelectedItem.Text;
    JToken fetchrecord = ddlcategories.SelectedItem.Text;
    string title = (string)result["title"];
    int brandid = (int)result["brandId"];
    string brandname = (string)result["brandName"];
    var upsc = Convert.ChangeType(result["upcs"].ToString(), type);
    var MPN = Convert.ChangeType(result["mpns"].ToString(), type);
    var maxSalePrice = Convert.ChangeType(result["maxSalePrice"].ToString(), type);
}
```

Comment: It throws the exception of "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty."

Comment: @DineshKumar Check edit, this is how I did it and it works just fine. Not sure how are you getting data.

Comment: Hello Sir,

Please use the API link to see the data.

Comment: @DineshKumar I'm downloading the string straight from your link and it's working just fine.

Comment: @DineshKumar you're already inside token with those values, no need for inner loops, try this out.

Comment: This is working right but sir Foreach loop execution is only one time and according to API  get the values only one time.I want to get all the values of upcs,MPN and listPrice.